# How to mock an enumerator in C#

Tags: c#, mocking, office-interop

I am using the Microsoft Office Automation model in C#. For example in Excel the Workbook object has a property called Sheets, containing an enumerable collection of Worksheet.
What I want is

```
interface IWorkbook { ISheets Worksheets { get; } ... }
```

Then an implementation:

```
class WorkbookImpl {
    private Excel.Workbook _workbook;
    public WorkbookImpl(Excel.Workbook workbook)
    {
        _workbook = workbook;
    }
    public ISheets Worksheets {
        get
        {
             // What goes here? something like
             return _workbook.Worksheets; // but obviously the type is wrong
        }
    }
 ...
```

The point is that I can later implemetent mocks of the various interfaces for IoC unit testing of the code.

Can you suggest how to get this done or do I have a totally wrong approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're effectively building an adapter layer between the Office Automation model, and your code. So, to adapt what you've already got:

```
class WorkbookAdapter : IWorkbookAdapter
{
    private Excel.Workbook _workbook;

    public WorkbookAdapter(Excel.Workbook workbook)
    {
        _workbook = workbook;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ISheetAdapter> Worksheets
    {
        get
        {
            return this._workbook.Sheets
                .Select(sheet => new SheetAdapter(sheet))
                .Cast<ISheetAdapter>();
        }
    }
}
```

..where `SheetAdapter` is something like:

```
class SheetAdapter : ISheetAdapter
{
    private Excel.Sheet _sheet;

    public SheetAdapter(Excel.Sheet sheet)
    {
        _sheet = sheet;
    }

    // Sheet properties, methods, etc.
}
```

You can cache the `SheetAdapters` in a list if it makes sense to, to avoid making the `Select` and `Cast` calls each time that the `Worksheets` getter is invoked.

Now when you're mocking, you can back your mock with a `List<ISheetAdapter>` or something similar, and avoid mocking en enumerator. Mocking enumerators or collection types is usually a code smell, and leads to all kinds of difficulties. Best to use an actual collection type.

Comment: This mostly worked, though I had to adjust it a little because the Excel collection classes are a little funky about Linq, so I used a foreach loop with yield return in the getter. However, you pointed me on the right path. Thanks.

Comment: @JessicaBoxer Great. `yield return` is a good alternative - I might update the answer to include that information.